# Python: Append a list to another list and Clear the first list

Tags: python, list

Consider this example at the REPL:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = []
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list2
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> del list1[:]
>>> list1
[]
>>> list2
[[]]
```

When I clear `list1` using `del list1[:]`, the contents of `list2` are also cleared. Why does this happen?

Comment: This might provide some insight: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Passing a `list` to a method like `append` is just passing a *reference* to the same `list` referred to by `list1`, so that's what gets appended to `list2`. They're still the same `list`, just referenced from two different places.

If you want to cut the tie between them, either:

1. Insert a copy of `list1`, not `list1` itself, e.g. `list2.append(list1[:])`, or
2. Replace `list1` with a fresh `list` after `append`ing instead of clearing in place, changing `del list1[:]` to `list1 = []`

Note: It's a little unclear, but if you want the *contents* of `list1` to be added to `list2` (so `list2` should become `[1, 2, 3]` not `[[1, 2, 3]]` with the values in the nested `list`), you'd want to call `list2.extend(list1)`, not `append`, and in that case, no shallow copies are needed; the values from `list1` at that time would be individually `append`ed, and no further tie would exist between `list1` and `list2` (since the values are immutable `int`s; if they were mutable, say, nested `list`s, `dict`s, etc., you'd need to copy them to completely sever the tie, e.g. with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for complex nested structure).

Answer (score 8):

So basically here is what the code is doing:

#### Before delete

[image]

#### After deleting

[image]

In short, both lists names are pointing to the same list object.

[code visualization source](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Alist2%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Alist1%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3%5D%0Alist2.append(list1%29%0Adel%20list1%5B%3A%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened with me as well.

```
original_list = ["a.csv", "b.csv"]                
copied_list = original_list
original_list.clear()
```

When I do so, both the lists (original_list and copied_list) get cleared. What worked for me as a solution of it,

```
original_list = ["a.csv", "b.csv"]                
copied_list  = original_list
original_list = [] # original_list  is refreshed with a fresh list.
```

This too also works,

```
original_list = ["a.csv", "b.csv"]
copied_list = original_list[:]
```

Thanks to @ShadowRanger.