# Text Cleaning Issues

Tags: python, text, nlp, topic-modeling

I'm learning text cleaning using python online.
I have get rid of some stop words and lower the letter.

but when i execute this code, it doesn't show anything.

I don't know why.

```
# we add some words to the stop word list
texts, article = [], []
for w in doc:
    # if it's not a stop word or punctuation mark, add it to our article!
    if w.text != '\n' and not w.is_stop and not w.is_punct and not w.like_num and w.text != 'I':
        # we add the lematized version of the word
        article.append(w.lemma_)
    # if it's a new line, it means we're onto our next document
    if w.text == '\n':
        texts.append(article)
        article = []
```

when i try to output texts, it's just blank.

Comment: what is doc ? how is it defined and initialized ?

Comment: Doc is a plain txt file

Comment: How do you open the file and read from it ? Can you show that part? Also, It would be good idea to put a `print(w)` right at the beginning of the for loop to see if w has any value

Comment: text = open("BioTest.txt").read()

Comment: And i tried to print w, it has value

Comment: you try using gensim -> preprocess_string to remove all stop words and .lower() for lowering the case.

from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import preprocess_string                     for w in doc: preprocess_string(w.lower())

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'texts' list and 'article'  list refer to same content and hence, clearing one list's content also clears the other list.

Here is a link to a similar question: [Python: Append a list to another list and Clear the first list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606601/python-append-a-list-to-another-list-and-clear-the-first-list)

Please see if the above are useful.